# git alias to merge and then rollback merged files as uncommitted

Tags: git, git-alias

I'm using git on Windows and I'd like to define an alias for the following workflow:

```
git merge <branch>
git reset HEAD~1
```

I tried the following in my got config file but it does something different than executing the 2 commands separately

```
[alias]
        rollback = reset HEAD~1
        rmerge = !git merge $1 && git rollback
```

I also tried the following permutations, but it still doesn't work as expected:

```
[alias]
        rollback = reset HEAD~1
        rmerge = !git merge $1 && git reset HEAD~1


[alias]
        rollback = reset HEAD~1
        rmerge = !git merge $1 ; git reset HEAD~1
```

How can I do this on Windows?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want `git merge $1 --no-commit`